# Outer product and flatten with vectorial operations - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing the following operation with a 2-d array `m` and a 1-d array `v`:

```
result = np.array([np.outer(v, m_row).flatten() for m_row in m])
```

However this is a lot slower than numpy pure vectorial operations, as I am using a list comprehension and a `np.array` at the end.

Can I do this `outer` product for each row in a matrix with only one operation? Or at least only using vectorial operations, without use of a loop or list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend dims and then use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(m[:, None, :]*v[:, None]).reshape(m.shape[0], -1)
```

Alternatively, with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ij,k->ikj', m, v).reshape(m.shape[0], -1)
```

---

For `m` of shape `(30, 5)` and `v` of shape `(6,)`:

```
%timeit (m[:, None, :]*v[:, None]).reshape(m.shape[0], -1)
# 5.93 µs ± 77.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.einsum('ij,k->ikj', m, v).reshape(m.shape[0], -1)
# 5.44 µs ± 61.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([np.outer(v, m_row).flatten() for m_row in m])
# 179 µs ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```